# Where can I get tiddlywiki?

Tags: tiddlywiki

I am trying to get it from the site here:

http://www.tiddlywiki.com/

Or the GTD version here:

http://nathanbowers.com/gtdtw/index.html#

And all I can see is a blank page.  Is there something I could do?

Comment: A blank page at those URLs or when you try to do a download? The pages themselves look fine to me.

Comment: Both (*******************)

Comment: @Tal: Usually it is best to use more descriptive text in comments not long enough rather than use placeholder characters.

Comment: will do me.Man.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: chrome - it's now solved.  Was probably my antivirus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be relevant:
http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/Corruption

Comment: Bingo - it solved the problem (I downloaded it as a zip)

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that you have `javascript` enabled and go straight to the [download page](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/#Download).
Click on the blue download button to save the file -- its called `empty.html`.

Or, use one of these links directly:

1. http://www.tiddlywiki.com/empty.html
2. http://www.tiddlywiki.com/empty.zip

Right-click and save the file to your desktop.

---

Update on comment:
I guess you'll need to add in some specifics.
What is the OS, Browser,
and if its firefox, have you tried something like Chrome, IE, Opera or such?

We need to know a bit more on your browsing experience... can you open other sites?
Can you reach [`http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/Downloading_TiddlyWiki`](http://tiddlywiki.org/wiki/Downloading_TiddlyWiki)?
If you can, can download `empty.html` as described there?
<sup>Its the same link as I gave above.</sup>

Comment: Thanks nik, this is what I tried, but all I get is an empty page (also in the main page of tiddlywiki.com).  I cleared the cache and my cookies.  What am I missing?

Comment: @talgalili What are you missing? Well the files obviously! ;)

Comment: If you're seeing nothing then chances are either you have javascript disabled (as nik mentioned) or you are using an old or odd version of a browser that does not render the page properly.